# AWS EC2 /dev/nvme1n1 mounted without partition table

Tags: amazon-ec2, disk-volume, partition-table, aws-ec2

I have an EC2 server on nitro system (c6g.2xl) where I have attached a 2nd volume. This is a web hosting environment and the disk is regularly increased in size.

For some reason I accidentally mounted the disk on - what I would call - the "partition table level", ie. my mount point is /dev/nvme1n1, not /dev/nvme1n1p1  - I can't recall how this happened, but it has the following effects:

- when I make the disk bigger, it is immediately bigger - I do not need to grow the partition table. In fact when I try growpart as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html I get an error:

  ```
  sfdisk: /dev/nvme1n1: does not contain a recognized partition table
  FAILED: failed to dump sfdisk info for /dev/nvme1n1
  ```
- I have successfully restored from a snapshot by attaching it as a 3rd disk

Given that seemingly all of the Internet has a partition table on this volume - what are the downsides of this approach?

Comment: At my place of employment we don't use partition tables for data volumes. Some far-fetched downsides  I can think of are (a) "smart" programs that manipulate disks thinking the volume is uninitialized and helpfully automatically writing a partition table to the disk and (b) novice sysadmins doing the same.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for a partition table on a data disk, it's only necessary if you want to boot from it. If you want to split a volume into smaller block devices, I'd suggest using LVM.

Comment: and would you view most guides as using a partition table though? Do you have an opinion why they do?

Comment: Mostly inexperience and a little bit of cargo-culting I guess.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

XFS:

```
sudo xfs_growfs -d /data
```

ext4:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme1n1
```